# como rodar uma EOF no R? pacote spacetime (ou clim.pact)

Tags: r, packages

Eu estou atualmente trabalhando com dados de fauna de foraminíferos para reconstrução da camada de mistura ao longo dos últimos 20ka. Nós fizemos a reconstrução a partir da abundância de algumas espécies, que representam camada de mistura mais profunda ou mais rasa e construímos uma curva (a partir de uma análise GAM), que mostrou essa variação.

Agora nós queremos encontrar padrões de séries temporais e espaciais dentro desses dados. No artigo "Late Quaternary coccolith records in the South China Sea and East Asian monsoon dynamics" (2013) - http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921818113001872 - os autores utilizaram uma análise EOF com o mesmo objetivo, no entanto, fizeram com um programa estatístico chamado PAST, que não possui a função EOF, mas esta foi feita a partir de uma PCA.

Gostaria de saber como essa análise EOF pode ser feita a partir de uma PCA (quais dados utilizar e como organizar, por exemplo) ou como proceder a análise EOF no R a partir do pacote spacetime (ou clim.pact) com as mesmas questões do past, sobre quais dados utilizar e como organiza-los."

Se alguém puder dar uma luz!

Comment: Olá Giggia, bem vinda ao SOpt! Sua pergunta foge um pouco do escopo de programação, pois tem um foco em estatística, por isso talvez seja mais difícil conseguir uma resposta por aqui. Para facilitar um pouco, sugiro que você poste um exemplo de dados que podem ser utilizados na análise. Vale a pena também fazer a pergunta no [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) (em inglês), onde certamente você encontrará mais estatísticos para te ajudar do que aqui.

Comment: Muito obrigada. Vamos escrever lá!